# can I be extradited to Manchester if I am from Manitoba, Canada and commit a crime in Manchester?

Tags: extradition

Now this is hypothetical, but let's say I visit Manchester, UK, but I live in Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada.
While in Manchester, I set a building on fire, or I murder someone.  Greater Manchester police figure out that I did it, and find out I'm in Winnipeg.
Can I get extradited to manchester even though I was born and raised in Winnipeg, or would I be charged in Winnipeg despite the fact the crime happened outside of Winnipeg and Canada's jurisdiction?  What would have to be done if I could get extradited to manchester to ensure my arrival in Manchester, given that Winnipeg to manchester involves an Inter-continental flight?

Comment: I just added wher I explain why I'm asking how this would work, given that I would be taking an inter-continental 6 to 8 hour flight between two continental areas. also there are no direct flights between Winnipeg and Manchester.

Comment: Why would an intercontinental flight cause any problems?

Comment: At best, the fact it's an international flight is relevant, but this is only because it's international: an international taxi ride or an international walk would be no different.

Comment: I mention this because I know that prisoners aren't allowed bathroom breaks on US flights where they are being transported, but inter-continental flights take a minimum of 6 hours using the pole.

Comment: With regard to bathroom breaks, that would be governed by the policy of the agency transporting the prisoner. I don't know whether that would be a Canadian agency or a UK agency.  The airline's policies might also come onto play.

Answer (score 1):

The UK has an extradition treaty with Canada, according to the Extradition Act 2003. So if all legal requirements are met, then yes you can be extradited.

Comment: Why would they fly the person through the US? It seems needlessly complicated. There are plenty of direct flights between Canada and the UK.  Why would extradition treaties with the US matter even if the person were flown via the US?

Comment: The first comment on the question made me think that the question was asking of a hypothetical situation where the UK and Canada didnt have direct flights. I'll edit my answer

Comment: What I meant by the first comment is that there are no direct flights that between Winnipeg and Manchester, though there are between Vancouver and Manchester.  the other part is if so how would the extradition happen given it' sinter-continental flights?

Comment: It doesnt matter if its intercontinental. As long as the country where the plane takes off has an extradition agreement with the country where the plane lands there is no problem

Comment: ah got you.  So let's say this happens, would I be transfered to the GMP authorities in Winnipeg Airport, Vancouver Airport or would the Canadian authorities accompany me on the flight to manchester?  I ask because the only direct flight to Manchester I know of is from YVR to EGCC. or is it case by case?

Comment: I have no clue. But that is a matter of bureaucracy rather than a legal issue. They could put you on a boat and ship you there if they wanted

Comment: Neither Winnipeg nor Manchester are relevant in any way: you would be extradited from Canada to England if you had committed a crime in England that is extraditable under Canadian law.

Comment: Not "if you committed a crime", but "if the UK can convince Canada that there is enough evidence that you should be prosecuted in the UK".